# CSS-Numbering Issue Mixed Numbering

Tags: html, css, counter

So I have the following header examples in HTML (like `<h1> class="roman">H1</h1>`)

```
I. H1
   a) H2
   b) H2
II. H1
   1. H2
   2. H2
```

another example would be

```
1. H1
   a) H2
   b) H2
2. H1
   2.1 H2
   2.2 H2
```

I am using automatic numbering with CSS and while the second example works fine what I get for the first example is

```
I. H1
   a) H2
   b) H2
II. H1
   0.1 H2
   0.2 H2
```

The problem lies in the leading 0 of the H2 numeration. That is because the CSS counter is still 0 and I am using a css counters like

```
h2.num:before {
     content: counter(H1) "." counter(H2) " ";
     counter-increment: H2;
}
```

and

```
h1.al:before {
     content: counter(H1LR, lower-latin) ") ";  
     counter-increment: H1LR; 
}
```

Is there a way to omit the counter value if it is 0 or is there another way to do this?

Here https://jsfiddle.net/j3g6rjer/3/ is a minimal example where even the increment is not working and also the leading zeros are a problem. What is wrong here?

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] in which this happens? With your example, it's not clear why you don't just use `content: counter(H2)` rather than including a counter that never increases.

Comment: see changes above

Comment: Is this what you wanted: https://jsfiddle.net/j3g6rjer/7/

Comment: Thanx danield that fixes part one of my problem...

Comment: @reencode The problem in your own fiddle is that you are trying to maintain four distinct counters, but since there is no h1 with class "num", the counter `section` never increments. Also, you reset `section2` in `body`, but not `section`. You should have written `body {counter-reset: section section2;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not displaying when it's 0 can't be done from CSS, maybe filter it out from javascript.

But it shouldn't be hard to fix. Try applying the counter-increment from the main counter and the counter-reset to 1 for the secondary counter directly to H1 tags, then counter-increment for the secondary on the h2 tags.

```
body {
    counter-reset: section;
}

h1 {
    counter-increment: section;
    counter-reset: subsection;
}

h1::before {
    content: counter(section) ". ";
}

h2::before {
    counter-increment: subsection;
    content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b6hq8x5t/1/